# MVContrib Portable Areas with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvccontrib

MVCContrib Portable Areas use WebForms engine to extract views embedded as resources from different assemblies. It would be a lot more natural with Razor, which is totally decoupled from the web runtime.

So, is there any work done to replace WebForms View Engine with Razor for Portable Areas? Haven't looked at the source yet, would it be easy to implement?